# Running a For Loop on a List

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I am new to using for loops. I have created a list of baseball teams. Within these team variables are 6 lists containing data from baseball-reference.com.  I am needing to access data from the 9th and 10th columns in the 6th list (These are just 2 of the 30 teams I will have in my full code).  My sample code is as follows:

```
library(XML)

bal <- "http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/BAL/2014-schedule-scores.shtml"
bos <- "http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/BOS/2014-schedule-scores.shtml"

mylist <- list(bal, bos)

a <- lapply(mylist, readHTMLTable)

for(i in 1:length(mylist)) {
  b[i] <- a[[i]][[6]][, c(9, 10)]
}
```

When I run this code I get an error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In b[i] <- a[[i]][[6]][, c(9, 10)] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In b[i] <- a[[i]][[6]][, c(9, 10)] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Here is the structure of the first of two lists in my variable a:

```
List of 2
 $ :List of 6
  ..$ NULL         :'data.frame':   13 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ V1: Factor w/ 13 levels "Â","Biggest Lead",..: 3 1 2 4 8 9 7 6 10 11 ...
  .. ..$ V2: Factor w/ 10 levels "0","1","11","12",..: 2 3 10 7 2 8 6 9 3 5 ...
  .. ..$ V3: Factor w/ 12 levels "","Â","last on Apr 1, counts all days of the season     including off days",..: 6 3 1 7 5 4 11 12 9 10 ...
  ..$ NULL         :'data.frame':   16 obs. of  6 variables:
  .. ..$ V1: Factor w/ 9 levels "Blowouts (5+ Runs)",..: 8 9 4 9 5 9 2 9 3 9 ...
  .. ..$ V2: Factor w/ 1 level "W": NA 1 NA 1 NA 1 NA 1 NA 1 ...
  .. ..$ V3: Factor w/ 1 level "L": NA 1 NA 1 NA 1 NA 1 NA 1 ...
  .. ..$ V4: Factor w/ 1 level "RS": NA 1 NA 1 NA 1 NA 1 NA 1 ...
  .. ..$ V5: Factor w/ 1 level "RA": NA 1 NA 1 NA 1 NA 1 NA 1 ...
  .. ..$ V6: Factor w/ 1 level "WP": NA 1 NA 1 NA 1 NA 1 NA 1 ...
  ..$ NULL         :'data.frame':   5 obs. of  6 variables:
  .. ..$ V1: Factor w/ 3 levels "Home/Road","Month by Month",..: 3 1 3 2 3
  .. ..$ V2: Factor w/ 1 level "W": 1 NA 1 NA 1
  .. ..$ V3: Factor w/ 1 level "L": 1 NA 1 NA 1
  .. ..$ V4: Factor w/ 1 level "RS": 1 NA 1 NA 1
  .. ..$ V5: Factor w/ 1 level "RA": 1 NA 1 NA 1
  .. ..$ V6: Factor w/ 1 level "WP": 1 NA 1 NA 1
  ..$ NULL         :'data.frame':   7 obs. of  6 variables:
  .. ..$ V1: Factor w/ 4 levels "Blowouts (5+ Runs)",..: 4 2 4 3 4 1 4
  .. ..$ V2: Factor w/ 1 level "W": 1 NA 1 NA 1 NA 1
  .. ..$ V3: Factor w/ 1 level "L": 1 NA 1 NA 1 NA 1
  .. ..$ V4: Factor w/ 1 level "RS": 1 NA 1 NA 1 NA 1
  .. ..$ V5: Factor w/ 1 level "RA": 1 NA 1 NA 1 NA 1
  .. ..$ V6: Factor w/ 1 level "WP": 1 NA 1 NA 1 NA 1
  ..$ NULL         :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  6 variables:
  .. ..$ V1: Factor w/ 1 level "Split": 1
  .. ..$ V2: Factor w/ 1 level "W": 1
  .. ..$ V3: Factor w/ 1 level "L": 1
  .. ..$ V4: Factor w/ 1 level "RS": 1
  .. ..$ V5: Factor w/ 1 level "RA": 1
  .. ..$ V6: Factor w/ 1 level "WP": 1
  ..$ team_schedule:'data.frame':   166 obs. of  21 variables:
  .. ..$ Rk        : Factor w/ 163 levels "1","10","100",..: 1 75 86 97 108 119 130 141 152     2 ...
  .. ..$ Gm#       : Factor w/ 163 levels "1","10","100",..: 1 75 86 97 108 119 130 141 152 2 ...
  .. ..$ Date      : Factor w/ 163 levels "Date","Friday, Apr 11",..: 40 140 100 5 50 76 30 118 143 2 ...
  .. ..$           : Factor w/ 2 levels "","boxscore": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  .. ..$ Tm        : Factor w/ 2 levels "BAL","Tm": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..$ Â         : Factor w/ 3 levels "","@","Â": 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
  .. ..$ Opp       : Factor w/ 21 levels "BOS","CHC","CHW",..: 1 1 1 6 6 6 12 12 12 20 ...
  .. ..$           : Factor w/ 24 levels "","1:05 pm","1:07 pm",..: 24 23 23 23 23 24 23 24 24 23 ...
  .. ..$ R         : Factor w/ 10 levels "","0","14","2",..: 4 4 5 6 8 5 4 3 7 2 ...
  .. ..$ RA        : Factor w/ 10 levels "","1","10","11",..: 2 8 6 3 9 2 6 7 6 5 ...
  .. ..$ Inn       : Factor w/ 2 levels "","12": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..$ W-L       : Factor w/ 13 levels "1-0","1-1","1-2",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  .. ..$ Rank      : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 4 5 5 4 5 4 3 5 ...
  .. ..$ GB        : Factor w/ 6 levels "0.5","1.0","1.5",..: 6 1 2 3 5 3 4 3 2 3 ...
  .. ..$ Win       : Factor w/ 11 levels "Britton","Buehrle",..: 1 6 4 10 9 11 5 3 7 8 ...
  .. ..$ Loss      : Factor w/ 11 levels "Archer","Chen",..: 6 4 2 3 7 11 4 8 5 10 ...
  .. ..$ Save      : Factor w/ 6 levels "","Hunter","Kelley",..: 2 1 6 1 4 2 3 1 2 5 ...
  .. ..$ Time      : Factor w/ 13 levels "2:20","2:34",..: 6 3 7 10 11 2 8 12 9 1 ...
  .. ..$ D/N       : Factor w/ 2 levels "D","N": 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
  .. ..$ Attendance: Factor w/ 13 levels "15,799","20,880",..: 12 5 2 4 7 8 13 9 11 3 ...
  .. ..$ Streak    : Factor w/ 6 levels "-","--","---",..: 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 5 6 1 ...
```

How do I fix this problem? And am I even on the right track with my method in using a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could not use a for-loop at all, but try `lapply` instead:

```
b <- lapply(a, function(x) x[[6]][, c(9,10)])
```

It is also usually a good idea to refer to columns by name instead of numbers. Especially if you don't have control over the original data. Then if they add another column, the numbers may change, but the names probably won't. So try this:

```
b <- lapply(a, function(x) x[["team_schedule"]][, c("R", "RA")])
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `b` is supposed to be a list as well? In that case, declare `b <- list()` somewhere before the loop, and use

```
 for(i in 1:length(mylist)) {
  b[[i]] <- a[[i]][[6]][, c(9, 10)]
 }
```

Note the double brackets.